# Installed something in pip in Python and Visual Studio doesn't recognized it

Tags: python, import, pip

```py
import termcolor
print(dir(termcolor))
```

Windows PowerShell

```bash
Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS F:\5\moh.py> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python39_64/python.exe" f:/5/moh.py/modules.py
  File "f:\5\moh.py\modules.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pyfiglet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfiglet'
PS F:\5\moh.py> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python39_64/python.exe" f:/5/moh.py/modules.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\5\moh.py\modules.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pyfiglet
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyfiglet'
PS F:\5\moh.py> & "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Shared/Python39_64/python.exe" f:/5/moh.py/modules.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "f:\5\moh.py\modules.py", line 36, in <module>
    import termcolor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'termcolor'
PS F:\5\moh.py>
```

Comment: How did you install `termcolor`? (show the command line you used with pip and/or virtualenv)

Comment: pip install termcolor

Comment: i installed it right but the proplem is the program dosn,t recognized it and then i reload tle program snd also dosn,t work